# Sequence of commands to determine param values based on other params

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4.2

A controller action needs to calculate values based on some params, the result of which needs to be updated in the same action

```
  def update
    calculate_weight_volume
    authorize @itme
    @itme.update(itme_params)
```

the method

```
def calculate_weight_volume
  if !params[:itme][:width].nil? && !params[:itme][:length].nil? && !params[:itme][:height].nil? && !params[:itme][:weight].nil?
    @weight_volume = (params[:itme][:width].to_d + 1) * (params[:itme][:length].to_d + 1) * (params[:itme][:height].to_d + 1) / conversion_factor
    if @weight_volume > params[:itme][:weight].to_d
      params[:itme][:weight_volume] = @weight_volume
    else
      params[:itme][:weight_volume] = @itme
    end
  end
end
```

is not being calculated with the params, but with the record's saved attributes.

Aside from the fact rails4 is using attributes for the calculations, it is obvious that the call to method `calculate_weight_volume` is being ignored before the update_params kicks in.

Why is that and how can this be overcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to modify sequence

```
def update
  authorize @itme
  @itme.update(itme_params)
  calculate_weight_volume
  @debit.update_attributes(amount: params[:correction][:newamount])
```

and change the method to update based on saved values

also, if updates on other models are involved, those actions should come after calculations

```
def calculate_weight_volume
  if !@itme.width.nil? && !@itme.length.nil? && !@itme.height.nil? && !@itme.weight.nil?
    @weight_volume = (@itme.width.to_d + 1) * (@itme.length.to_d + 1) * (@itme.height.to_d + 1) / conversion_factor
    if @weight_volume > @itme.weight.to_d
      @itme.update(weight_volume: @weight_volume)
    else
      @itme.update(weight_volume: @itme.weight) 
    end
  end
end
```

I was expecting multiple hits to the database, but noticed that if the data is unaltered, *no commit* is executed.  Not as inefficient as I thought. But still feels stupid.